# Limiting API requests with observables

Tags: angular

This is the first time I've tried this and isn't working, someone can guide with an example?.What I'm trying to do is when you click a sign in button only let you to do one http-request to the API no more but i need it to do it with observable's now i have it with promises. How can i do that?

- The disabled attribute is the one that disabled or no my button

***This is my ts file where i limit the requests but with promises***

```js
async sendAdmin(){
    this.bSignIn = true;
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('email', this.loginForm.get('email').value);
    formData.append('password', this.loginForm.get('password').value);
    this.disabled = true;

    // using delay for http response
    await this.delay(3000);
    this.disabled = false;
    this.adminService.validateAdminCredentials(formData)
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        this.bSignIn = false;
        let auxRes: any = res;
        if(auxRes.type == 'success'){
          let auxUser = {
            firstName: auxRes.first_name,
            personId: auxRes.id,
            clientId: auxRes.client_id
          }
          this.isSigned = true;
          localStorage.setItem('leadLoggedAdmin', JSON.stringify(auxUser));
          this.goToAdminDashboard(auxRes.first_name);
        }
      },
      err => {
        this.bSignIn = false;
        this.openSnackBar(this.snackMessage);
        this.loginForm.reset();
      }
      );
  }
  private delay(ms: number){
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }
```

***This is what i tried but doesn't work ***

```js
async sendAdmin(){
    this.bSignIn = true;
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('email', this.loginForm.get('email').value);
    formData.append('password', this.loginForm.get('password').value);
    this.disabled = true;
    this.adminService.validateAdminCredentials(formData)
    .pipe(
      delay(200),
      mergeMap(() => this.myObservable()),
      tap(() => this.disabled = false)
    )
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        this.bSignIn = false;
        let auxRes: any = res;
        if(auxRes.type == 'success'){
          let auxUser = {
            firstName: auxRes.first_name,
            personId: auxRes.id,
            clientId: auxRes.client_id
          }
          this.isSigned = true;
          localStorage.setItem('leadLoggedAdmin', JSON.stringify(auxUser));
          this.goToAdminDashboard(auxRes.first_name);
        }
      },
      err => {
        this.bSignIn = false;
        this.openSnackBar(this.snackMessage);
        this.loginForm.reset();
      }
      );
  }
  private myObservable() {
    const observable = Observable.create(observer => {
        observer.next();
        observer.complete();
    });
    return observable;
  }
```

***ValidateAdminCredential function that has the endpoint and apiurl***

```js
validateAdminCredentials(user: any){                              
    return this.http.post(this.API_URL+'NONE-NONE-2/'+ENDPOINT_NAME+'/login/', user, this.httpOptions);
  }
```

***A little example of the stackblitz i use ***

- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nmencc
- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qe11v1

Comment: What are your requirements?

Comment: When the user try to log in into the page if he click the sign in button several times the app only should do one http-request to the API, see the behaviour that should have in the examples of the question, i tried to implement it with observable's but doesn't work in my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `take` from  `RxJS`

**Emit provided number of values before completing.**

**Why use `take`?**

When you are interested in only the first emission, you want to use take. Maybe you want to see what the user first clicked on when they entered the page, or you would want to subscribe to the click event and just take the first emission. Another use-case is when you need to take a snapshot of data at a particular point in time but do not require further emissions. For example, a stream of user token updates, or a route guard based on a stream in an Angular application.

- If you want to take a variable number of values based on some logic, or another observable, you can use takeUntil or takeWhile!
- take is the opposite of skip where take will take the first n number of emissions while skip will skip the first n number of emissions.

[Source and examples](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/take#examples)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `shareReplay` operator on an observable to share a response with multiple subscribers. You will need to persist the common observable that can be shared with all subscribers.

service.ts

```js
// cache current http requests using the url as a key
private httpRequests = {};

// the service function that is subscribed
getData(): Observable<any> {
  const url = 'http://mock.com';

  // return ongoing request
  if (this.httpRequests[url]) {
    return this.httpRequests[url];
  }

  // cache and return new request
  return this.httpRequests[url] = this.makeHttpRequest(url).pipe(
    // share with all subscribers
    shareReplay(1),
    // remove cached request
    finalize(() => delete this.httpRequests[url])
  );
}

private makeHttpRequest(url): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(url);
}
```

This is a technique for ensuring that no additional http requests go out for a given url while another response is pending for that same url. You would use UI techniques such as disabled buttons in addition to this.

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kxezk1